# ASP.NET Error "The specified network password is not correct"

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, .net

I have a .NET application running on server 2008 running IIS 7.5 that has two sites bound to the same IP address. A customer has moved the application root for one of the sites by accident to a network drive and now I am getting the error "The specified network password is not correct" even now that I've changed the directory back to the correct one and verified that the security permissions are correct. The other site is running fine, but I can't work out what I need to do to get this one working.

Hopefully someone can help me with this!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All web-access related settings are lost when accidentally (or otherwise) moving content out from under however it was configured in IIS previously.

This includes network access permissions, directory security settings, certificates, everything.

FYI, the most common reason for the error you show is that the site is served over the (Windows/UNC) network but not secured via SSL; this is not normally allowed without some major tweakings to the network account running that site.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What I can't work out though is how to set the permissions back again. Do you know how I can reset it back to how it was before without having to re-install the application again!? Thanks